# Не работает layermask для raycast2D unity

Tags: unity3d

В скрипте есть переменная для установки слоев т.к нужно добавлять несколько, но raycast ee игнорит

```
[SerializeField] private LayerMask playerLayer;
```

После этого проверил несколько вариантов, тоже самое, абсолютный игнор, что это может быть? Работаю с 2d

```
LayerMask.GetMask("Player")
1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player")
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не добавил длину луча т.к raycast идет из камеры, следовательно значение маски шло в параметр длины, а маска оставалась пустой.

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(CameraManagement.I.gameCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition),Vector2.zero, 10, playerMask)
```